# React : pass socket.io to props

Tags: javascript, sockets, reactjs

I try to pass my socket connection to my props.

here my code :

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../redux/actions.js'
import Main from './main.jsx';

let socket = io(`http://localhost:8090`);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    MyState
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch),
    socket: bindActionCreators({socket}, dispatch)
  }
}

const App = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);

export default App;
```

It doesn't work. My socket object is empty inside my props. I think it expected a function like actions. How can I pass my socket object to my props ?

Thank for your answer

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm currently working on a similar problem: how to pass the result of an express server API call to my client-side react/redux app.